# X11 - Hide windows from screen cap

Tags: linux, x11, c++

I'm aiming to hide X11 Windows from screen capture software such as discord/obs,
Within windows i am able to do this using [SetWindowDisplayAffinity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity) on windows, but on X11 i have struggled to find a similar way to do this.

If this seems unreasonable or unreachable, having a black window render on OBS but not from the perspective of the user would again be a good alternative.

If anyone knows anyway i can do any of these, please send me some links to documentation or examples!

And yes i have only recently got into developing software specifically for linux so i am very open to hearing any of your thoughts on this topic.

Comment: Can't you just capture a single X11 window?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Im not sure how that helps me?, could you elaborate a bit, sorry

Comment: Yh id prefer to be able to primarily capture the entire screen, and if unmapping the window allows the user to see the window in some capacity (and click etc) while being hidden from OBS etc then i think that would be a good way for me to go about it?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264542/record-screencast-on-nonactive-workspace may be helpful

Comment: Kinda helpful yeh, but not really what im hoping for,
Not too sure if what im asking is really possible in X11, 
Seeing as windows and X11 handle windows very differently